# visual studio 2008 sp1 std::string::c_str() err

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory, std

i had met same situation in my project. 
The following code were similarly reproduced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class METHOD
{
public:
vector<METHOD*> m_arg;
string name;
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
METHOD()
{

}
METHOD(string n)
{
    name = n;
}
};

class PF : public METHOD
{
public:
PF(){};
};

void main()
{


PF p;
p.m_arg.push_back(new METHOD(string("a")));
p.m_arg.push_back(new METHOD(string("b")));
p.m_arg.push_back(new METHOD(string("c")));

for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)p.m_arg.size() ; ++i)
{
    const char* ccs = p.m_arg[i]->getName().c_str();  //PROBLEM POINT

    size_t ss = strlen(ccs);
}

}
```

the problem is //PROBLEM POINT
the return address of **c_str()** can't be assigned to **const char* ccs**. 
in debugger, the **css** assigned memory address of return of **c_str()**, but **css**'s value is "" and it work same as ""

but the next code is working as expected.

```
    string str("ok");
const char* ckk = str.c_str();
```

after this code, **ckk** points after **str.c_str()** returnning addres, and **ckk**'s value in debugger is "ok"

the same problem is occuring in std::wstring, wchar_t, unicode.

why did this problem occur?
who knows? help me plz~

ADD:
thanks to mystical i solve the problem same way. but this solution also work OK.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)p.m_arg.size() ; ++i)
{
    string& strr = p.m_arg[i]->getName();
    const char* ccs = strr.c_str();
    size_t ss = strlen(ccs);
}
```

so i think the return value of **getName()** is live until the loop } closed. 
but interestingly, the next is don't work

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)p.m_arg.size() ; ++i)
{
    string* strr = &p.m_arg[i]->getName();
    const char* ccs = strr->c_str();
    size_t ss = strlen(ccs);
}
```

the css is 'dangling' and also strr is "" 
i've dazed and confused!

Answer (score 4):

In your `getName()` function:

```
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

The string that is returned is a copy of the original. It becomes an intermediate in the following expression:

```
const char* ccs = p.m_arg[i]->getName().c_str();
```

When the expression ends, that intermediate is destroyed. Therefore invalidating the pointer returned by `c_str()`. **The result is that `ccs` becomes a dangling pointer.**

The reason why this works:

```
string str("ok");
const char* ckk = str.c_str();
```

is because `str` is not an intermediate.

**To make it work, change your loop to this:**

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)p.m_arg.size() ; ++i)
{
    string str = p.m_arg[i]->getName()
    const char* ccs = str.c_str();

    size_t ss = strlen(ccs);
}
```

**EDIT : To answer your new question:**

The reason why this doesn't work:

```
string* strr = &p.m_arg[i]->getName();
```

is the same as before. `getName()` returns an intermediate. You then take the address of this and assign it to `strr`. The intermediate is destroyed after the statement, so `strr` becomes a dangling pointer as in the first case.

Comment: Another fix would be to have `getName()` return a `std::string const&` (and the function itself should be `const` as well). Then the expression is valid and there is no copying of the string involved.

Comment: You could also go a step further and inline it into the `strlen`. But the loop is clearly incomplete since `ss` is never used.

Comment: `strlen` is also quite dubious; `std::string::size()` is O(1) not O(n).